# How can I move an existing index on a normal table to a memory optimized file group?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, filegroup, memory-optimization

How can I move an existing index on a normal table to a memory optimized file group in sql server?

Comment: You don't. Memory optimized file groups are for memory optimized objects only, and you can't have a memory optimized index on a regular table -- it'd be impossible to keep in sync efficiently. (Well, not impossible, but unreasonably difficult to the point where it would defeat the purpose.) Nor can you convert a regular table to memory optimized on the fly; you have to create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible,

Unless you move the table!